# Caching for I/O intensive S3?

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am writing a video messaging service and the videos will be stored on amazon S3. The nature of video messaging will involve a lot of writing and reading from the S3 storage. Basically as soon as it's written it will be read by another client. I am worried that S3 cannot keep up with the speed and will delay the message delivery time. I already have CloudFront CDN + S3 setup, I wonder if CloudFront is enough to serve as a cache or do I need to setup some sort of memcaching layer above the S3?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

CloudFront + S3 should be enough, but do test your assumptions, use multipart upload and measure it all, as this guy did: http://improve.dk/pushing-the-limits-of-amazon-s3-upload-performance/

> At the top, I was pushing more than one gigabyte of data to S3 every second - 1117,9 megs/sec to be precise. That is an awful lot of data, all coming from a single machine. Now imagine you scale this out over multiple machines, and you have the network infrastructure to support it - you can really send a lot of data.